# How to find the average of the ODD/EVEN rows in the column 2 when I have a set of data with 10 columns and 5 rows in LINUX

Tags: linux

How to find the average of the ODD/EVEN rows in the column 2 when I have a set of data with 10 columns and 5 rows in LINUX?
Can some one help please.

for example:

1 **2** 3 4 5;

2 **5** 3 2 5;

3 **4** 4 7 9;

5 **3** 8 9 3:

average odd rows of column 2 = (2+4)/2 = 3

average even rows of column 2 = (5+3)/2 = 4

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? If you did and it didn't work, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` makes it:

```
awk 'NR%2 {o+=$2; odd++; next}
     {e+=$2; even++}
     END{print "odd:", o/odd; print "even:", e/even}' file
```

For your sample file it returns:

```
$ awk 'NR%2 {o+=$2; odd++; next} {e+=$2; even++} END{print "odd:", o/odd; print "even:", e/even}' file
odd: 3
even: 4
```